# why take an typescript error with union type?

Tags: typescript

```
interface Bird {
  age:string,
  eat:()=>any
}

interface Fish {
  age:string,
  swim:()=>any
}
type Pet = Fish | Bird;
```

this is ok, set a Pet type

```
const pet:Pet={
  age:"sd",
  eat:()=>{}
}
```

when return a Pet type, But this take an error.

```
function test():Pet{
  return {
    age:"sd",
    eat:()=>{}
  }
}

test().eat(); //take a typescript error
```

My question is why  they are same typescript `Pet`, but `test().eat()` take an error

Comment: Can you show the error

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code:

```
interface Bird {
  age:string,
  eat:()=>any
}

interface Fish {
  age:string,
  swim:()=>any
}
type Pet = Fish | Bird;
```

so objects of type `Pet`:

- definitely have attribute `age` because it's in both `Fish` and `Bird`, and
- at least one of `swim()` or `eat()` because if it had neither it wouldn't be a `Fish` or `Bird`, however we don't know which (NB. It could have both).

The problem is that your factory function `test():Pet` is declared to return a `Pet` which might be a `Fish` without the `eat()` function.  So `test().eat()` gives a type error.  It's true that `test()` happens to return a `Bird` as an implementation detail, but the return type doesn't reveal that.

To see this, try changing the `test():Pet` to one of:

- `test():Bird`, or
- `test()` with no declared return type and let the type inference work it out.

Comment: yes I can do this, But why factory function can not infer return `Bird ` type

Comment: It can infer the type if you remove the explicit return type.  With the explicit return type `Pet`, you are establishing a contract with other code that uses that function to expect a `Pet` without specifying which one.  In the current implementation, it happens to return a `Bird` but it's not committing to that.  It's like it's saying "test() always return a `Pet`... right now it's a `Bird` but this might change in future and client code shouldn't break when it does".  It's the type error that ensures client code won't break when later `test()` might return a `Fish`.